# How does Amoeba forcing add a measure 1 set of random reals?

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, forcing

Amoeba forcing is defined as follows:

$\begin{equation*}
(\mathbb{A}, \leq) := (\{X \subset 2^{\omega} : X \text{ is open and } \mu(X) < 1/2\}, \supseteq)
\end{equation*}$.

It is claimed that this forcing notion adds a measure 1 set of random reals. I get that if $G$ is $(\mathbf{V}, \mathbb{A})$-generic then $2^{\omega} - \bigcup G$ is a perfect set of random reals over $\mathbf{V}$ of measure 1/2. But how do we recover a set of random reals of measure 1 from the generic filter?

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like a symmetric argument to show that $\bigcup G$ also contains a set of measure $\frac12$ of random reals?

Comment: The argument that $2^{\omega} - \bigcup G$ are all random reals hinges on $\bigcup G$ covering all ground model null sets. I am not seeing any obviously symmetric argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you have a set $S$ of random reals with measure $1/2$, I think the Lebesgue density theorem lets you improve the measure as follows. (I'll work in $[0,1]$, but everything transfers to $2^\omega$.) For any positive integer $n$, there's a rational interval $I$ whose intersection with $S$ has at least $1-\frac1n$ of the measure of $I$. Linearly stretch $I$ to $[0,1]$ and you have a set $S_n$ of random reals with measure at least $1-\frac1n$. Now take $\bigcup_nS_n$.

(Actually, this is even easier in $2^\omega$: Take the set of all tails of sequences from $S$. As far as I can see, you still use the Lebesgue density theorem to see that this works.)

Comment: Clever. Very hipstery.

Comment: Ah yes. So the rational translates of the perfect tree $2^{\omega} - \bigcup G$ (of which paths are all random reals) form a predense subset of the random real forcing in $\mathbf{V}[G]$, and hence the union of the paths through them forms a measure 1 set.